# How to plot three categorical values?

Tags: r, plot

I have data like the following (three categorical values):

```
data <- data.frame(Comp = (rep(c('Oral','Text'), each = 8)), 
                   Cat = rep(c('Declative','Non-declative'), 4), 
                   Type = rep(c('Free','Used'), each = 4))
```

I want to have an interaction.plot or barplot with these three categorical values in R. Would you give me any tip?

Comment: Does it have to be a single plot or could it be two plots that are next to each other? You may want to look at the vcd package.  For a two-variable plot you can create mosaic plots with Comp and Cat with one for the Free group next to one for Used..

Comment: @Elin Probably, you are right. Can you give me any formula? To be frank, I am really a beginner in this field.

Answer (score 0):

Although your supplied data don't produce a good display since the cells are all equal sized you can use base r to make a mosaic plot.

```
data <- data.frame(Comp = (rep(c('Oral','Text'), each = 8)), 
                   Cat = rep(c('Declative','Non-declative'), 4), 
                   Type = rep(c('Free','Used'), each = 3))
mosaicplot(table( data$Comp,data$Cat,data$Type))
```

Here's a variant on your data that shows it a little better.

```
data <- data.frame(Comp = (rep(c('Oral','Text'), each = 8)), 
                   Cat = rep(c('Declative','Non-declative'), 4), 
                   Type = c(rep(c('Free','Used'), each = 3), c('Used', 'Used')))
mosaicplot(table( data$Comp,data$Cat,  data$Type))
```

Of course you can go to specialized packages to get other variations,  vcd is one but if you search you will find others.